# Simple form 'selected' attribute not setting correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form setup for a model. Although it's not working correctly.

```
<%= f.input :folder, collection: current_user.folders, label_method: :name, value_method: :slug, selected: params[:folder] %>
```

I'm setting the `selected` attribute of the input through the parameters. So if the url ends like this: `?folder=First+Folder`, I'd want the the input to search throught the collection set in the code above (i.e., `current_user.folders`) and set that as selected. And it sort of works but not really.

Say the options in the select tag are like this

- First Folder
- Second Folder
- Third Folder

***No matter what the value of params[:folder] is,*** the select tag will always have the first option selected. In this case: "First Folder". It doesn't matter if `params[:folder]` is set to "Second Folder" or "Third Folder". It will always be set to "First Folder" or the first option in the select tag.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. option instead of "selected" put "value: params[:folder]"
2. I think a more elegant solution is in controller let's say you have model "File". Because value could be changed and selected will have the wrong value

```rb
def new
  @file = File.new
  @file.folder = params[:folder]
end
```

Comment: `folder` is an `ApplicationRecord`, not a string.

Comment: doesn't matter, do it from controller `@file.folder = Folder.find_by(id: params[:folder_id])`

Comment: Well, I'm already sort of doing that. However, I need for the select tag to have a folder selected ***automatically***. The only way I could think of having the select tag have an option selected automatically with the folder the user selected on a previous screen was to pass the name of the folder passed through the params. But that's not working, the select tag isn't showing the selected folder automatically. In fact, it's showing the wrong one automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I needed to pass the slug to the selected attribute, not the name. If you're implementing this, your probably using the `id` instead of the `slug`. In any case, this is what worked for me.

```
<%= f.input :folder, 
  collection: current_user.folders, 
  label_method: :name, 
  value_method: :slug,
  selected: @folder.slug
%>
```